# Select from multiple table columns with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a search button that can filter through multiple table columns within a table, I have three seperate codes that can search a data on a particular table column (LastName, FirstName and DriverID):

```
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection();
Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PC-PC\\MIKO;
                        Initial Catalog=Caproj;
                        Integrated Security=True;";
Con.Open();
string qry = "select LastName from [Driver Table] where LastName=@id";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, Con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", slastname.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da2.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
  MessageBox.Show("Valid Input");
 }
else
{
 MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input");
}
```

Is there a way where I can search them all at the same time without the need for making a separate filter for each? Something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, DriverID 
FROM [Driver Table] 
WHERE LastName=@id 
  AND FirstName=@id 
  AND DriverID=@id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, don't you just want `or`:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, DriverID 
FROM [Driver Table] 
WHERE LastName = @id OR
      FirstName = @id OR
      DriverID = @id;
```

Or, more simply:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, DriverID 
FROM [Driver Table] 
WHERE @id IN (LastName, FirstName, DriverID);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this what you need. 
But this query will return a **1** value when the id is existing from the 3 columns.

```
SELECT  
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Driver Table] WHERE LastName = @id) 
            THEN 1 
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Driver Table] WHERE FirstName = @id) 
            THEN 1 
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Driver Table] WHERE DriverID = @id) 
            THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
    END
```

Comment: Do I just remove the "1", If I only want it to select the statement without returning a 1 value?

Comment: If that's the case just replace the AND to an OR on your query.